# Uncertainty-Correlated Qubits

Tags: quantum-computer

How does one make a pair of collections of qubits that naturally obey an uncertainty relation between them

For example given collections of qubits $Q^1 = q_1^1, q_2^1 ... q_k^1$ and $Q^2 = q_1^2,q_2^2... q_k^2$

I want to set up a system where any observations of $Q^1$  necessarily send $Q^2$ into a superpositional state.

It's not clear how to cook this up in the Quantum Circuit model, as one could always collapse all qubits going into the circuit and observe both systems exactly.

Comment: Why don't you put $Q^2$ into an independent superposition state right from the beginning?

Comment: Well no what I want to have is I observe some subset of  $Q^1$, say I get some values (1 0 0 .... ) (whatever), I now observe some subset of large subset of  $Q^2$ (maybe all of it), now despite having already collapsed the state of $Q^1$ and not acted on it by any quantum gates, if I observe $Q^1$ I should see that its 'values have changed. I.E. When I observe $Q^1, Q^2$ the act of observation on one, necessarily implies lack of information about the other

Comment: Much like how on a particle, if I localize somethings position very accurately, and put it at a point $x_1, x_2, x_3$, then I localize its momentum very carefully, if I look at the point $x_1, x_2,x_3$ I probably won't find the particle

Comment: @NorbertSchuch the point where the suggestion falls short is because if I just put $Q^2$ into an independent superposition from $Q^1$ then observe ALL my qubits, store the values, don't do any quantum gate stuff, and observe the qubits again, the values won't have changed at all

Comment: But isn't this all basis dependent?  If you collapse into a well defined state in one basis, this is automatically a superposition in some other basis.

Comment: This is true... and a bit unsettling

Comment: Let me think, I might be flawed in how I modeled the idea here